# Android App to play video Instant like Tiktok

Tags: exoplayer, android-video-player, instant

I have developed an app where I am displaying users videos, those can be of 15 minutes long, that is why I have transcoded all the videos in **HLS** format in AWS Bucket with the help of lambda function and I am serving those videos through cloud front **CDN** and playing video in **ExoPlayer**, But I still getting leg in playing video. I want that it should be play instantly like **TiTok**. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you find anything?